# Excel blob reconstruction = corrupted file

Tags: javascript, excel

My server is transferring me a `.xls` file (headers below) with content-type `application/vnd.ms-excel`

```
"cache-control": "public"
"content-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel"
"last-modified": "Thu, 21 Mar 2019 09:25:53 GMT"
```

So I create the file on my client using the blob technique but the data inside is all over the place (file opens but tables are broken).

```
const file = new Blob([response.body], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
const href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

I cannot find a solution as why.

few things I tried:

opened the file on the server and it is ok so that confirms the problem is on transfer or client blob reconstruction

transferring as base64 instead of binary: same problem so that confirm the problem is on the blob reconstruction part

full javascript (binary)

```
export(context, type, callback) {
    context.$http.get(config.api_url + config.export_path + type,
        {responseType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'}
        )
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                const file = new Blob([response.body], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
                const href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                // success
                callback(context, 'success', href);
            } 
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })

},
```

full javascript (base64)

```
exportBase64(context, type, callback) {
    context.$http.get(config.api_url + config.export_path + type
    )
    .then(response => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.file) {

                const txt = atob(response.file);
                const file = new Blob([txt], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
                const href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                // success
                callback(context, 'success', href);
            } else {
                // error
                callback(context, 'error');
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })

}
```

Comment: You’re saying that data are correctly read so only failure is they are spread across the doc? If so have you tried the endings ("native"/"transparent"[default]) option param?

Comment: Yes kind of, the data is not in the correct cells and is also broken into weird characters; I did not try `native"/"transparent"[default]` As per my research seems that transparent is the default option so I would need to try native I guess

Comment: I tried specifying `ending: 'native'` as second argument op options but that did not work